# Select all rows matching a string of comma separated values from same table

Tags: mysql, sql

My table structure is like this:

```
row_id    col_1     col_2
------    ------    ------
1         title1     2,4,5
2         title2     1,2
3         title3     4
4         title4     2,5
5         title5     3,4
```

I would like to select all titles from `col_1` where the row_id exists in `col_2`.

So for example if I was to query just the first row, I would like the query to return:

```
1 | title1 | title2, title4, title5
```

Comment: Spend that time auto creating proper tables utilizing group_concat. Your problems are only beginning if you don't

Answer (score 0):

That is not good to store data like this (meaning the `col2` field, to be more specific, storing comma-separated values). You should take a look at normalization and store `col_2` data in another table with a separate row for each value.

For example:

```
create table tbl1 (
  row_id int primary key,
  col_1 varchar(20)
);

create table tbl2 (
  parent_id int,
  child_id  int, /* col_2 in your example */
  foreign key (parent_id) references tbl1(row_id),
  foreign key (child_id) references tbl1(row_id)
);
```

Then you can easily get the result you want:

```
select t2.parent_id
     , group_concat(t1.col_1)
from tbl2 t2
join tbl1 t1 on t1.row_id = t2.child_id
where t2.parent_id = 1
group by t2.parent_id
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3230d/3)